# How to enable lint check only for project library?

Tags: android, gradle, lint

My project includes many modules, and I want to enable static code analyze for some of them. Thus I do following test, but it failed. Below is my library's build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
        ignoreWarnings false
        checkReleaseBuilds true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

And below is my app's build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hp.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
        ignoreWarnings false
        checkReleaseBuilds true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile project(':mylibrary')

}
```

And I add a lint error in my library, below is mylibrary lint and ./gradlew assembleRelease result

```
hpdeMac-Pro:MyApplication hp$ ./gradlew mylibrary:lint

> Configure project :app
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.

> Task :mylibrary:lint
Ran lint on variant release: 2 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 2 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///Users/hp/Downloads/MyApplication/mylibrary/build/reports/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to file:///Users/hp/Downloads/MyApplication/mylibrary/build/reports/lint-results.xml


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mylibrary:lint'.
> Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.

  Fix the issues identified by lint, or add the following to your build script to proceed with errors:
  ...
  android {
      lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
      }
  }
  ...

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
23 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 16 up-to-date
hpdeMac-Pro:MyApplication hp$ ./gradlew assembleRelease

> Configure project :app
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
51 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 50 up-to-date
hpdeMac-Pro:MyApplication hp$
```

Would you like to explain why ./gradlew assembleRelease can't find the lint error and how to enable static code check for modules only? Thanks a lot.